# parse rs.status() output to display one secondary node for mongodump destination

Tags: backup, mongodb, scripting

I wish to run mongodump to secondary (not primary). So I need as output hostname and port of one secondary.

```
# ./mongo  -udbadm admin --port 27100 -p --quiet --eval "printjson(rs.status().members.map(function(m) { return {'name':m.name, 'stateStr':m.stateStr} }))"
Enter password: 
[
        {
                "name" : "example-1.domain:27200",
                "stateStr" : "SECONDARY"
        },
        {
                "name" : "example-2.domain:27200",
                "stateStr" : "PRIMARY"
        },
        {
                "name" : "example-3.domain:27200",
                "stateStr" : "SECONDARY"
        }
]
```

With shell script tools is no problem for me to extract one secondary with hostname and port.
My question howto do this job the MongoDB way? What tools do you recommend me?
I heard that `jq` is better for JSON data. But don't know howto extract only one secondary host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's worth noting that if you pass in a [replicaset string](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--host) into `mongodump` it defaults to reading from a secondary from the set (note: in 3.0.5+ this is not the case if you connect to a `mongos` in a sharded cluster).  If your replica set name was repl1 it would be something like:

```
./mongodump --host repl1/example-1.domain:27200,example-2.domain:27200
```

For reference, in the more recent versions (since the tools were re-written in `Go`), this is done by setting [`Monotonic` mode](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Session.SetMode) when not connected to a `mongos` (source from 3.0.6 [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/r3.0.6/mongodump/mongodump.go#L95)).

To answer your specific question, a really simple way to parse rs.status() is with a filter, and it will fit on one line:

```
rs.status().members.filter(function(rsStatus) { return rsStatus.state === 2;})[0].name
```

That will return the name field of the first (hence `[0]`) secondary (`state === 2`) found in the array of members returned by `rs.status()`

Comment: Except for the change of  for 3.0.5, this behavior seems to be undocumented. Is this worth a ticket?

Comment: It used to be documented I am pretty sure (though I can't dig it up now).  Given some of the comments in the tickets, it seems it may not yet be final that secondary is the default, but it has been that way for some time.  It is implied by the note about the behavior when connected to the mongos, but not explicitly stated, so probably worth a DOCS ticket

Comment: "If the string passed to --host is prefixed by the replica set name, mongodump reads from the primary"

seems to have changed since then

Comment: The tools have been completely rewritten in Go since this, and there have been several major versions released, so I expect many things have changed

Answer (score 1):

No need to use another tool, you could just:

```
./mongo  -udbadm admin --port 27100 -p --quiet --eval "rs.status().members.find((m) => m.stateStr === "SECONDARY").name"
```

to get:

```
example-1.domain:27200
```

Note that the `find` method will return the first element found.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will give you 1 secondary:

```
# ./mongo  -udbadm admin --port 27100 -p --quiet --eval "var i=0; rs.status().members.forEach( function(myDoc) { if (myDoc.stateStr=='SECONDARY' && i==0) { print(myDoc.name); i++;} })"
```