# Capturing mongo replica set state from mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, scripting

I am trying to capture mongo replica set state from mongo shell. E.g.

```
[root@server ~]$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.6.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.8
rs0:SECONDARY>
```

I'd like to capture that `SECONDARY` keyword, and to **do it in one command**. I've tried something like `mongo > output`, however it requires a manual `ctrl+c` to terminate the process.

I have tried
[parse rs.status() output to display one secondary node for mongodump destination](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114437/parse-rs-status-output-to-display-one-secondary-node-for-mongodump-destination/114441)

But the solution doesn't always work. Different mongo version can output different message. `ARBITER` node does not have authentication data either.

Answer (score 2):

The output you are trying to capture is the default prompt for the `mongo` shell in interactive mode.

As at MongoDB 4.0 there isn't a built-in helper to return replica set member status as a string, but you can derive the same status in JavaScript.

For example, create the following as `getstate.js`:

```
    var mystate = 'UNKNOWN';

    // Note: isMaster command does not require authentication
    var isMaster = db.isMaster();

    if (isMaster.msg == "isdbgrid") {
        mystate = "mongos";
    } else if (isMaster.ismaster && !isMaster.setName) {
        mystate = 'STANDALONE';
    }

    if (isMaster.setName) {
        if (isMaster.secondary) {
            mystate = 'SECONDARY';
        } else if (isMaster.arbiterOnly) {
            mystate = "ARBITER";
        } else if (isMaster.primary === isMaster.me) {
            mystate = 'PRIMARY';
        }
    }

    print(mystate);
```

Now invoke `mongo` using `--quiet` to suppress any startup messages or warnings:

```
$ mongo localhost:27017 getstate.js --quiet
PRIMARY

$ mongo localhost:27018 getstate.js --quiet
SECONDARY

$ mongo localhost:27019 getstate.js --quiet
ARBITER
```

Comment: This is a nice script, I will implement it. However I still have problem with `arbiter` when authentication enabled. Since `arbiter` does not have auth data, this method will return `Error: Authentication failed`. Is there a way to determine whether mongo is `arbiter` or not, before running this script?

Comment: @HowardLee The [`isMaster` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/isMaster/) (as used by drivers and clients) intentionally does not require authentication. I simplified the script example so you should now be able to run against any replica set member without auth.

Comment: NOTE: in general I would advise against using arbiters for production deployments where possible. An arbiter provides election availability without contributing to write availability so there are important caveats if a data bearing member is unavailable. For example, it is no longer possible to acknowledge majority writes in a Primary-Secondary-Arbiter config with one data member down (which in turn can impact cache pressure and usage of some newer features like Change Streams in 3.6+). A replica set with only a healthy Primary and Arbiter also does not have any active replication.